# Chirpy tutorial or documentation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, chirpy

I want to use [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) to minify my js files. Unfortunately, I can't find any [documentation](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/documentation). The only link given is [down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.weirdlover.com).

EDIT: if someone knows of a better tool, feel free to propose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the page you linked:  [dotnetchunks tutorial](http://www.dotnetchunks.com/Article/Chirpy%20-%20VS%20Add%20In%20for%20Handling%20CSS,%20JS,%20DotLess%20and%20T4%20files/54#.UcsN4JwwthF)

Comment: aaa down as well, 404 :/ it seems that chirpy's being shot everywhere